# MySQL - TRIM not removing whitespace, how do I ascertain what type of whitespace it is?

Tags: mysql, whitespace

I have whitespace in a field.

I have tried to use `TRIM()` but it isn't removing the whitespace.

So, how can I work out what type of whitespace it is?

Comment: How about a curse - HEX() ??

Comment: Never used it (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex)  Just trying to work out how to remove it but not sure exactly what it is!

Comment: The idea is to use `HEX` to figure out what kind of character your whitespace is exactly. Example: `SELECT HEX(RIGHT('wordwithwhitespaceattheend ', 1))` returns `20` which is the hexadecimal representation of a space.